# How would you design/implement the notification model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I've got a User model. The app has registered users and registered artists. A user can be identified as an artist or a registered user through the Roles model.

In my account page, I've got a notification section.

User notifications are difference from Artist notifications.

For example. A registered artist can set the following notifications:

- Email me when a User likes my painting
- Email me when a User comments on my painting

A registered user can set the following notification:

- Email me when my favorite artists posts new paintings

Both user and artist can set the following notification:

- Email me when someone sends me a private message

How would you go about designing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A roles model? I'm not so specialized in roles, and stop me if I'm wrong, but I would probably just assign `role` as an attribute of a `user` model. Then I would allow all users the ability of having all notifications, and in the haml/html differentiate between what they see based on their role.

So your HAML would say :

```
- if current_user.role?(artist)
  = f.label 'Email me when a User likes my painting'
  = f.select :notification_option
- if current_user.role?(user)
  = f.label 'Email me when my favorite artists posts new paintings'
  = f.select :notification_option
= f.label 'Email me when someone sends me a private message'
= f.select :notification_option
```

Comment: Hmm interesting solution. This means you are suggesting I have is_artist (BOOLEAN) and is_member (BOOLEAN), or the likes, in the user model directly?

Comment: On the same note, should there also be a Notification model?

Comment: @Fazzini, your first question, no not boolean. I would keep this a string. That way it opens up the possibilities of having an admin as well and using the same model. I have even theorized using integers. Where the # represents the rank of user. 1 being a regular user. 2 being an artist, and 3 being admin and so on. Your second question, yes. If you are using rails 2 then make a notification model. if you are using rails 3, then no. Just genereate a mailer with `rails g mailer my_mailer` .

Comment: Also the point of using numbers is that you can write easy conditional like this page is viewable by `User.role > 2` . Where then it would be good for let's say an admin, and super admin. Where admin has access to the back-end, and super admin is your CEO who has even more secret access.

Comment: What if a user is a regular user and an admin? Or if a user is an artist and an admin? I am not sure if having integers is the most logical way of representing a user's role. I may be mistaken. It's my first time implementing such a thing in Mongodb. But if it has worked for you in previous projects, then I am willing to give this approach a try :-)

Comment: About Notifications. I am using Rails 3. If I don't have a model, how would I track how notifications should be sent for specific users?

Comment: It really depends on the nature of the application. Hmm..if artists can be admins.. then maybe an additional attribute of admin would suffice. User(:role => "artist OR user", :admin => "true OR false")

Comment: @Christian Fazzini, about notifications.. does a user have many sets of notifications? If it only has one set of notification, in your case, three or four different preferences of what emails to be sent, does that need to be attached to a seperate model? I would think not..and that those could also be attributes to the same model of the user class. But I'm open to suggestions. I have heard of `has_one` relationships working. But usually they are in the case like `Worker :has_one Project_Manager` . And that makes sense because that manager has many polymorphic relationships elsewhere.

Comment: I'd like to think long-term. For now there are only 3 or 4 types of notifications. The future may lead to several more types of notifications. At the moment, I am thinking that I should have notifications embedded to the User collection. And as the app grows (i.e. the need allow more notification types), I could easily add notifications.

Comment: The only problem is in the web form. I would have to manually input each notification by hand instead of having it go through a loop. Something like: <% Notification.all.each do |notification| %> <%= check_box_tag '[notification_ids][]', notification.id, @user.notifications.include?(notification) %> <%= label_tag notification.description %> <% end %> Or is there a better way?